# Is there a Windows app out there that can pipe command line arguments into a TCP socket connection?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, socket

I haven't needed anything like this before but I'm sure something exists. I'm looking for a compiled Windows executable (i.e. noninterpreted language) that I don't need to write that can read the arguments passed in on the command line, open an TCP network socket to another machine, and pass the arguments along.

Has anyone used something like this before?

re: netcat for windows: Yeah, basically. Problem is I'm trying to get data out of a WhatsUp installation and onto another box as events are triggered. I can't specify a full command line, just an executable and as a separate field the arguments to pass in, so I can't do any pipe tricks.

AFAIK netcat can only read data from STDIN or a pipe, but there's no way to specify the data as a command line argument. man page seems to support this. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You can always have the executable be a batch file that does something like this.  "echo alert data | nc [options]"

Comment: That batch file command should have been "echo %* | nc [options]".  That will pass all the arguments that WhatsUp passes to the executable to netcat.

Comment: Actually, that might be doable. Always forget about good 'ol .bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you basically you want [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) for Windows.  And it looks like someone ported it [here](http://joncraton.org/blog/netcat-for-windows).

Comment: It exists, and I've used it. Unfortunately every antivirus product on the market will flag it as malware, so you'll have to add an exception to use it.

Comment: You could try ncat from nmap 5.0+.

Comment: Somewhat. I've edited in my reservations about netcat.

Answer (score 0):

psexec from Sysinternals will execute on a remote host.
or use hyperterm or telnet to send the data to a specific port.

Comment: Unless that host isn't Windows.

Comment: Oh.. Now I understand. Then I guess you would have to script the telnet command on the windows box. I guess it looks like syslogish kind of deal,.